# React fetching data twice

Tags: reactjs, firebase, use-effect

I am trying to fetch some data from google's firestore in an useEffect, and saving it in useState variable

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchFirst = async () => {
        ...
        // setting the new found data in a useState
        setData1(data1)
    }
    fetchFirst()
}, [])
```

Now, I want to fetch some other data from firestore, but this data requires some information from previous fetched (fetchFirst) data. I tried to do this but does not work

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchFirst = async () => {
        ...
        // setting the new found data in a useState
        setData1(data1)
    }
    const fetchSecond = async (data1) => {
        ...
        // setting the new found data in a useState
        setData2(data2)
    }
    fetchFirst()
    fetchSecond(data1)
}, [])
```

My first fetch works completely fine, but when my code reaches the second fetch, the input data (`data1`) is null. Can someone please help me figure it out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your using async you should wait, with the `await` keyword, for the first fetching to finish, then use its result in the `fetchSecond`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchFirst = async (): SomeData => {
    const data = await fetch(...);
    return data;
  };

  const fetchSecond = async (data: SomeData) => {
    await fetch(...);
  };

  const fetchAllData = async () => {
    const data = await fetchFirst();
    await fetchSecond();
  };

  fetchAllData();
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

Both function are `async`. You need to call `fetchSecond` when `data1` value changes:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchFirst = async () => {
        ...
        // setting the new found data in a useState
        setData1(data1)
    }
    fetchFirst()
}, []);


useEffect(() => {
    const fetchSecond = async (data1) => {
        ...
        // setting the new found data in a useState
        setData2(data2)
    }
    fetchSecond(data1)
}, [data1]);
```

Or call `fetchSecond` inside `then` block

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchFirst = async () => {
        ...
        // setting the new found data in a useState
        setData1(data1);
        return data1 //--> return data value
    }
    const fetchSecond = async (data1) => {
        ...
        // setting the new found data in a useState
        setData2(data2)
    }
    fetchFirst().then(data => fetchSecond(data));
    
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call your second inside your first function call and pass data that you're setting in the state rather than passing state data.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchFirst = async () => {
        ...
        // calling the function with new found data
        fetchSecond(data1)

        // setting the new found data in a useState
        setData1(data1)
    }
    const fetchSecond = async (data1) => {
        ...
        // setting the new found data in a useState
        setData2(data2)
    }
    fetchFirst()
}, [])
```